# Minimal number of grid points to form cube with dual contouring? (voxels)

Tags: algorithm, graphics, voxel

I have been learning about the [dual contouring algorithm](http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf) which is useful since it allows surfaces to contain both smooth and sharp edges. I am somewhat confused over how the input data is used. I believe that I would better understand this if I understood how a minimal sharp cube was defined.

Having spent quite some time reading various resources I have come to believe that one of the following ideas is correct, but I have been unable to determine which. To avoid confusion lets call the surface a cube and any 8 neighbouring grid-points a cell. An illustration would be very warmly appreciated to help illustrate the construction.

**Idea #1** - A minimal sharp cube is defined by a 2x2x2 grid where each grid point equates to a corner of the formed cube.

```
+---+
|   |
+---+
2x2x2 grid points / 1 grid cell
```

**Idea #2** - A minimal sharp cube is defined by a 3x3x3 grid where each grid cell contains a so called "feature point" and it takes 8 feature points to form the cube.

```
+---+---+
| . | . |          +---+
+---+---+   ===>   |   |
| . | . |          +---+
+---+---+
3x3x3 grid points / 8 grid cells
```

**Idea #3** - A minimal sharp cube is defined by a 1x1x1 grid where one grid cell of a certain density leads to the formation of a minimal sharp cube.

```
+
1x1x1 grid points / 0 grid cells
```

Here is another reference which may be of use to future readers:
http://upvoid.com/devblog/2013/05/terrain-engine-part-1-dual-contouring/

Comment: Idea #2 is correct. Do you have any other questions on the algorithm? Keep in mind that the algorithm is used to extract polygonal surfaces from implicit surfaces.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Awesome thanks! if you convert that to an answer I will accept :) Also thanks for the reference to "implicit surfaces" since this caused Google to throw all sorts of additional content at me which I had been missing!